# Encrypt a web api request body content and decrypt on server

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to create a simple security solution for which web API body content is not simply displayed to all whom wishes to see via intercepting the request with Fiddler or something. I am restricted in that I cannot use a SSL. I have already implemented a HMAC type of authentication and am wanting to take it a step further by creating a encrytpion of the body content on the client and sending that request to server were the server will then decrypt the body and forward to action as expected but decrypted. I used a filter for the server side HMAC and a delagatingHandler on the client.

I am not very familiar with working with http requests and do not fully understand how I might intercept all body content then encrypt it and put it back into the httpcontent.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you can't use https? That seems the way to go

Comment: `https` handles the encryption for you. No sense in reinventing the wheel and even if you did chances are it will never be as secure as https could be. *That is part not a jab at your skills as a developer but a statement of how well thought out and secure most standards are.*

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Information Security than here

Comment: The client runs on very specific configurations of which only port 80 is available. cannot use 443 and so we are unable to use ssl.

Comment: If you **really** cannot use TLS (and I would fight back on this requirement, and you can technically run [TLS on port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/227096/how-to-make-apache-port-80-secure) if necessary), you **must** be sure to securely encrypt the data with a cipher and block mode that provides integrity and confidentiality -- AES/GCM, EAX, or CCM. Implementing your own HMAC tag is unnecessary, but really, **please use TLS**. This stuff is very hard to get right, and the internet has provided years of attacks on TLS to demonstrate its value and fixes.

Answer (score 6):

In order to decrypt data before Model Mapping occurs in WEB API you can Hijack the **AuthorizeAttribute**  because **ActionFilterAttribute** occurs **after** model mapping.

I know that the AuthorizeAttribute is meant for another reason , but hijacking it worked perfectly for me (I wanted to decompress zip content).

```
    public class DecryptAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
      public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
      {
              actionContext.Request.Content =  DecryptContect(actionContext.Request.Content);
      }
    }
```

Then Decorate all your WebAPI controllers with this attribute.

In order to compress and embed to body i used a **Delegating Handler**

```
    public class EncryptHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>((responseToCompleteTask) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = responseToCompleteTask.Result;
                response.Content = new EncryptContent(response.Content);

            return response;
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }
}
```

Then just register it

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new EncryptHandler());
```

Comment: Thank you @Anestis Kivranoglou .So can you please show me your DecryptContext function? Does it return a HttpContent derived instance of sorts? I do have a IAuthenticationFilter implementation already and this implements a HMAC sort of authentication so to verify and constartint that only requests coming from certain client are processed. I have been thinking I can simply encypt and decrypt the body content in here I am mostly concerned with my inexperience with http stuff ,therefore the HttpContent type. It has many members and no obvious SetContent while there is a CopyContent to get it.

Comment: I don't have Encrypt-Decrypt Logic,  i just posted the functions for example.
I use this wraper for compress-decompress to gzip. You have to figure out your way to encryp-decryp string content

Comment: For anyone, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75383848/14401306) on how to assign the content after decryption.